# How to implement user access control mechanisam in web application

Tags: java, spring, user-management, accesscontrolservice

Am developing a web application using Springs. To make a scalability for my application am in need of user management system. In application having different groups each groups having different users.Every user having different roles.

- **To implement access control mechanism any API's available?**
- **How to assign role for every users?**

Comment: You can use apache Shiro.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Spring Security domain-acls](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/domain-acls.html) is a good choice for you. You can take a look at **Contacts** sample first to decide whether it is fit for you.

Comment: All ready am using spring security 3.1. Here i need a high level User management module. Any API's for this?

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur, see the documentation link in my answer. If you want the api, refer to [spring security apidocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/apidocs/). Spring Security domain-acls is not complicated to use, but it will be invasive to your code. The **Contacts** sample is really good material for you if you want to apply spring security to your app.